# Generate crontab for odd time intervals

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cron, cronexpression

I am planning to monitor some values in a system between time intervals. I am implementing quartz scheduler. I wanted to understand how to generate crontab which will have the following attributes:

1. Runs between 9:45- 12:30
2. Interval - 15 mins
3. Weekdays

The closest I was able to get was

```
0/45 9-12 * * Mon-Fri
```

which is roughly “At every 0 and 45th minute past the 9, 10, 11 and 12th hour on Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu and Fri.”

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use a cron string to set at the same time a minute interval and a minute start / end. For example, you can do this:

```
0 0/15 9-11 ? * MON-FRI
```

to run every 15 minutes between 9 and 12 (11.59) or this

```
0 15 9-12 ? * MON-FRI
```

to run at 9.15, 10.15 etc.

What I suggest you is to use more than 1 cron schedule using multiple triggers, as suggested [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06.html).
Or, even simpler, do not use cron but use the `TriggerBuilder` utility.

Hope it helps :)